# Which tool is recommended for a PostGIS design?

Tags: postgis, database-model

I need to create a design for a spatial database. I've found this list http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/GUI_Database_Design_Tools, but it seems to me that this software is orientated towards a regular (not spatial) DB design.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can try this one http://www.prodevelop.es/en/products/MOSKitt/MOSKittGeo ...and here ( https://confluence.prodevelop.es/display/MOSG/How-To+Install+Moskitt+Geo+Plug-in ) you can find how to install the geo module.
We hope will soon be aligned to the new release of postgis 2.0.

hope I've given you some good advice I wish you good work!

Comment: Thank you! Seems it is the right and free(!) tool! Too bad that they do not provide x86_64 versions since 1.3.2...

Answer (score 0):

yes, you are true. all database modeler which you had given is for normal databases. but in a gis conference i have heard that [Sybase PowerDesigner](http://www.sybase.com/products/modelingdevelopment/powerdesigner) tool has spatial support for modeling databases. i dont use it but there is some information here. [TECHNOLOGY OF GENERATING SPATIAL DATABASE BY USING POWERDESIGNER](http://en.cnki.com.cn/Article_en/CJFDTOTAL-CHXG200703011.htm).

i hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

I use the 'PostGIS Manager' plugin in QGIS (in addition to pgAdmin III.)  It performs quite a few handy tasks such as writing triggers to calculate areas of polygons on create and update.

On edit: Somehow I failed to notice that your question focused on 'design'.  So this answer might not be as useful.  Then again, "Spatial is not special."